# Mysql JOIN query taking so long or timeout to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have database for delivery of items to customers. for this i have 4 tables, delivery_logs, delivery,driver,customer

(we have delivery log table cause some time one delivery have many entries like not delivered & other driver take delivery etc)

```
delivery_log

id delivery_id driver_id  message     date_added
1  1           1         OK         2016-09-13 17:38:15 
2  2           2         OK         2016-09-13 17:35:18 
3  1           1         Not OK     2016-09-13 17:33:10     
4  1           3         OK         2016-09-13 17:32:13 
5  2           4         waiting    2016-09-13 17:20:11 


delivery
delivery_id  customer_id name          status
1            1           delivery 1    done
2            1           delivery 2    done
3            2           delivery 3    done


driver
driver_id  name
1          driver1
2          driver2
3          driver3

customer
customer_id  first_name   last_name
1            name1          other name1
2            name2          other name2
3            name3          other name3
4            name3          other name4
```

now i want to have query of

> last 1 record (order by date_added) from delivery_log
>
> for each delivery by each driver
>
> where delivery= done

and i want to have bellow fields

```
delivery_log.delivery_id  delivery_log.driver_id delivery_log.message date_added 
delivery.name driver.name 
customer.first_name customer.last_name
```

I am using bellow query & its result fine, but its taking so long & most time time out, cause my `delivery_log` table have almost **911065** records.

```
SELECT 
    dl.*,
    del.name,
    dr.name,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name
FROM delivery_log dl
JOIN delivery del 
 ON(dl.delivery_id = del.delivery_id)
JOIN driver dr 
 ON(dr.driver_id = dl.driver_id)
JOIN customer c 
 ON(del.customer_id = c.customer_id)
WHERE del.status IN('DONE','OK')
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM delivery_log s
                 WHERE s.delivery_id = dl.delivery_id
                   AND s.driver_id = dl.driver_id
                   AND s.date_added > dl.date_added)
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What indexes do you have you your tables?

Comment: 900k records isn't a big deal. POst your `show create table` output and the results of EXPLAIN for that query

Comment: Hello, in delivery_log table only ID is index and in every table ID is index only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add two indexes to delivery_log. One for delivery_id and one for delivery_id and driver_id.